# Must declare the scalar variable "@start"

Tags: sql, percentage, datediff

I want to calculate the date difference and calculate the percentage. While using the given below query showing one error. the error is : `Must declare the scalar variable "@start".`

Query :

```
SELECT
((30 * 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day, @start, @end)) * 250)
AS Percentage1,
((50 * 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day,@start, @end)) * 250) 
AS  Percentage2
```

Comment: where is declaration of `@start` variable

Comment: I suspect that you've not included your entire script. I also suspect that between your variable declaration and the part you have posted is the keyword `GO`. `GO` starts a new batch, and variables only exist for the duration of the batch.

Comment: Check my answer and do not forget to accept It as correct answer If It helped for you. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can declare variables in following:

**With default values:**

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '2014-01-02', -- pass default values
        @end   DATE = '2015-01-04'  --

SELECT
((30 * 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day, @start, @end)) * 250)
AS Percentage1,
((50 * 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day,@start, @end)) * 250) 
AS  Percentage2
```

---

**With [SET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx)**

> Sets the specified local variable, previously created by using the
>   DECLARE @local_variable statement, to the specified value.

```
DECLARE @start DATE, 
        @end   DATE

SET @start = '2014-01-02' -- pass any values
SET @end   = '2015-01-04'  --

SELECT
((30 * 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day, @start, @end)) * 250)
AS Percentage1,
((50 * 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day,@start, @end)) * 250) 
AS  Percentage2
```

---

Both ways returning following result:

```
   Percentage1          Percentage2
2043.596730245000    3405.994550408500
```

Comment: Hi Stanislovas, I don't want to pass date directly into the query.              I want to take start date and date from text boxes given in my page.

Comment: What programming language do you use? and what are names of textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

@start and @end are the variables you used in your query which should be declared with respective data types. Here your data type is seems to be DATE

```
Declare @start DATE
Declare @end DATE
```

and assign some values to it by using SET

for example

```
SET @start=(select getdate())
SET @end=(select getdate())
```

then you can use them in your query and that should be declared to some variable.

**Note**: If you are using any variable in query you should assign total query to one variable and execute it beacause while at runtime query will throws error as variables not found

```
Declare @sql  nvarchar(max)
set @sql='select '+ @start+ ', '+ @end
```

then `Exec(@sql)`